# Post Data with WebClient

Tags: json, vb.net, curl, webclient

I am trying to setup the ability to change a Twitch channel's title, game, and delay using a WebClient. Twitch's API documentation gives an example for doing this:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' -H 'Authorization: OAuth <access_token>' \
-d "channel[status]=Playing+cool+new+game!&channel[game]=Diablo&channel[delay]=0" \
-X PUT https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_channel
```

I can get the header portion working properly, I just don't know to handle the -d or post data portion. I've tried creating a NameValueCollection and using UploadValue. I've also tried UploadString.

Can someone point me in the right direction? How should the above example(expecially the -d part) be handled in VB.net using a WebClient?

Addition to show new method resulting in unauthorized:

```
    Dim address As String = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" & Channel.TrimStart("#")
    Dim data As String = "channel[status]=" & ChannelTitle & "&channel[game]=" & Game & "&channel[delay]=" & Delay
    Dim method As String = "PUT"
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    client.Headers("Accept") = "application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json"
    client.Headers("Authorization") = "OAuth " & AuthCode
    Dim reply As String = client.UploadString(address, method, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like Twitch wants you to HTTP PUT a string with your parameters. You might try:

```
Dim address As String = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_channel"
Dim data As String = "channel[status]=Playing+cool+new+game!&channel[game]=Diablo&channel[delay]=0" 
Dim method As String = "PUT" 
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reply As String = client.UploadString(address, method, data)
```

I'm not too familiar with curl so if that doesn't work maybe -d somehow processes the string into JSON, in which case you might try using the NameValueCollection again but sending it with UploadString with ToString().

Is this how you've tried using UploadString? What was the result?

Comment: Well I think I made progress. I was getting 404s but now I'm getting unauthorized. Although I'm not sure why, I've successfully used this method in the past. I edited the OP with the code.

Comment: Do you see any issues with my current example?

Comment: You might have some luck with Json.net if twitch is expecting JSON. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json